# Reference request for generalization of groups with out identity element?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, terminology, groupoids, magmas

In other words what do we call a magma which is  associative and has divisibility  property but not existence of identity? Or a groupoid when it loses the identity property?

A reference on such objects would be very helpful.

There is a table of various generalizations of groups [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid#Relation_to_groups) & [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)#Types_of_magmas)

Comment: The first one sounds like a cancellative semigroup (assuming that is what you mean by the divisibility property).

Comment: If by divisibility you mean $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ have solutions for all a,b then you have a group.

Comment: Since you have selected an answer then you may up-vote it as well?

Comment: I just rolled back an edit which changed perfectly acceptable English idiom to non-standard idiom. It's _what do we call_, not _how do we call_

Comment: Funny, *how do we call* would be the direct translation from Spanish :)

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill and German and French if I recall correctly. To be honest, I am not keen on such edits even if they are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think such structures are called nonunital semigroups. See, for example,
ftp://ftp.math.ethz.ch/EMIS/journals/MPRIA/2000/pa100i2/pdf/100210ai.pdf (Non-Unital Semigroup Crossed Products, by N.S. Larsen) and http://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2014/463918/ (Solution of Several Functional Equations on Nonunital Semigroups Using Wilson’s Functional Equations with Involution, by J. Chung and P. K. Sahoo).

Nonunital rings, which are more popular than simply nonunital semigroups, are discussed in answers to this MO question: [What are the reasons for considering rings without identity?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22579/what-are-the-reasons-for-considering-rings-without-identity)