# Which rings are the endomorphisms ring of some abelian groups?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, abelian-groups

Which rings are (isomorphic to) the endomorphisms ring of some abelian group? Is there any necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254056/does-every-ring-with-unity-arise-as-an-endomorphism-ring/254143

Comment: Also every ring is a subring of the endomorphism ring of its underlying abelian group. See: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27971/why-is-there-no-cayleys-theorem-for-rings