# Between abstract and concrete: What's the right way to think of specific categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question

At the risk of annoying some of the categorists I feel urged to pose this beginner-ish question:

If one talks about a specific category such as ***the*** *category of sets with functions* or ***the*** *category of groups with group-homomorphisms* or ***the*** *category of topological spaces with* <strike>*homeomorphisms*</strike> *continous maps* (let's restrict to these), what should I have in mind, how should I think of it?

1. a sheer structure of point-like objects and
   arrows which is merely isomorphic to
   a class of set-theoretic objects
   with set-theoretically definable
   morphisms between them (e.g.
   functions as sets) or
2. the class of set-theoretic objects **itself** (plus morphisms) or
3. what else?

In case of (1) shouldn't for example the category of sets been termed "the (abstract) category which is isomorphic to the (concrete) class (not *category*!) of all sets with functions" (as we would talk about "the unlabelled graph X which is isomorphic to the labelled graph Y")? And only because this is inconvenient, we talk of "the category of sets"?

[Added:] It's [common talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_sets) to say "**Set** is the category whose objects **are** all sets...". This sounds like taking position (2).

<strike>Side-question: There is the notion of "the category of models of a theory with elementary maps". Is the category of groups with group-homomorphisms the same as the category of models of group theory with elementary maps? If not so: why?</strike> (Made a separate question out of this.)

Comment: I just changed "homeomorphism" to "continous map".

Comment: Hans, it sounds to me like what you should do is curl up with a nice book like Mac Lane which will presumably explain many of these issues and more.

Comment: Even Mac Lane defines **Set** as "the category of all small sets" (p. 12) and I read this "whose objects **are** the small sets". Can you point me to a location where ML faces my question, or is it just implicitly answered (like the "inner structure" of an object is just implicitly determined by its hom-sets)?

Comment: And then I stumbled over this (p. 10): "A category (as distinguished from a metacategory) will mean any interpretation of the category axioms within set theory." So Mac Lane is siding with position (2)? What then about your answer below?

Comment: My understanding is that what Mac Lane calls a metacategory is what most people are happy to call a category, for example the nLab (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category).  But I'll wait until a real category theorist weighs in on the issue.

Comment: In any case, what I think Mac Lane means by "interpretation" is that there is a set (class?) of objects and a set (class?) of morphisms between two objects, not that the objects themselves need be regarded as sets in any way.

Comment: But what can a set (class?) "within set theory" be other than a set (class?) of sets?

Comment: Regardless of what particular axiomatization of set theory you use, there is no requirement for the morphisms to be functions.  

Comment: But nevertheless classes (of (functions as) sets), e.g. homotopy classes?

Comment: ZFC does not require all sets to be pure sets.  It's intentionally vague about that.  It's just that all specified constructions are sets.

Comment: Hans, all I mean is that the morphisms of a category where the objects are sets need not be functions between the objects!  For example, consider the category of sets and relations.  Is this so hard to understand?

Comment: No, it's not.
Thanks for your many hints, I guess we should stop the discussion here.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing really particular to categories about this question.  You may as well ask:

If one is talking about a specific group, say **the** group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, should one think of it as:

1. a set of three "atoms" labeled a, b, c, together with a multiplication law (aa = a, ab=b, ...) and a zero element (a), or
2. a set {a, b, c} of three *particular* *sets*, say a = {}, b = {{}}, c = $\aleph_4$, together with an addition law...?

I'm sure everyone has their own personal preference.  For me, (1) corresponds more closely to my intuition, but as long as you understand the relevance of the notion of [evil concepts](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/evil), there's nothing you can't do with (2) as well.

Comment: If I think of $\mathbb{Z}$'s standard model (pairs of naturals in the von Neumann standard model) I would firstly think of **the** group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as a set consisting of three equivalence classes on $\mathbb{Z}$ and after that I would abstract from this model and think of the group abstractly (like you do in 1). It never would come into my mind, to think of this group as in 2.

Answer (score 2):

There's a "really close correspondence" between quivers and categories, where quivers are directed graphs that can have multiple arrows from one vertex to another one and also loop arrows, which are arrows from a vertex to itself.  Isomorphisms become undirected edges.  This is a really good and precise way to think about it, because this viewpoint generalizes very nicely to some models of higher catgory theory, specifically A. Joyal's theory of quasicategories.  The whole beauty of category theory is that all of the information about an object is contained within its arrows, and that the underlying thing that the category represents is not actually important.  That is, we have all of the information about the category by: a.) Knowing the structure of the graph of the category.  b.) knowing the structure of the hom-sets (which don't always have to be sets), and c.) in extra structure that lives over the graph (like a grothendieck topology or a model structure (this is unrelated to the models you were talking about.  It has to do with abstract homotopy theory).  The only place that it's nice to have sets is for defining the hom-sets in an unenriched setting.  Without some notion of a set, it's hard to get important theorems like yoneda's lemma.  Lawvere famously came up with two categorical foundational theories, ETCC and ETCS.  At the moment, ETCC is pretty much useless.  It contains ETCS as a subaxiomatization, but all of the structure axiomatized in ETCC can be constructed from ETCS (depending on if you take the topos of sets to be boolean or not, and some other unimportant technicalities).

ETCS = Elementary theory of the category of sets

ETCC = Elementary theory of the category of categories

Comment: I've never heard of those "extra structures". How do they come in?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the vivid discussion in the comments after the question (and hopefully, also of some interest for the question itself):  I think that a "metacategory" is a definition by axioms, using only first order language, while "interpretation" means: an interpretation as in logic (say, as in p. 29 of Ebbinghaus-Flum-Thomas).

So such an interpretation (a category) is a set, or for convenience, several sets: A set of "objects," a set of "arrows" two function (that is, two more sets) "dom, cod" from the set of arrows to the set of objects, a function "1" from the objects to the arrows, a function "$\circ$" on the pairs of composable arrows, etc., that satisfy the first order axioms of a metacategory.

In summary, I agree with the comment of  Qiaochu Yuan: set theory is involved, but not because the objects should somehow be "sets with structure."

Answer (score 1):

Position 2 is only tenable because the categories you describe automatically come with forgetful functors to $\text{Set}$.  But in order to think about more general categories (say, homotopy categories) you can't and shouldn't think this way.  One way to resolve this situation is to define "concrete category" to mean a category **together with** a particular forgetful functor to $\text{Set}$, since a particular abstract category may be concrete in more than one way and the functor encodes extra information.  In other words, I guess I'm siding with Position 1.

**Edit:**  With regard to your edit, as Harry says, there is some set theory necessary to set up category theory, so it all depends on your approach.  But I would say that defining a category to be "the category of these kinds of sets with these kinds of functions between them" is no different from defining a group via one of its faithful actions or representations or defining a manifold via one of its embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^n$.  While we pick a particular instantiation to describe what we're talking about, we then talk about the abstract thing.

Comment: Would you agree then, that "the category of sets" is a convenient shortcut for "the (abstract) category that is isomorphic to the class of all sets with all functions between them". Or doesn't this make sense?

Comment: @Hans: To my knowledge, every definition of a category uses some of the theory of sets to develop the basic results in category theory.  As I said before, and as you can read the discussion on the nLab, ETCC is not very good at all.  I am not aware of a single useful result from ETCC that doesn't also appear as a consequene of ETCS.  

Comment: @Qiaochu, we specifically want an adjoint pair of functors rather than just a particular forgetful functor.  

Comment: @Hans: Perhaps this nLab entry is relevant: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cocomplete+well-pointed+topos

Comment: @Qiaochu: Even if there is no forgetful functor from a homotopy category to **Set**, one can think of the homotopy classes as classes of (functions as) sets, or am I wrong?

Comment: In any case, there should be *one* way of thinking of *all* categories, and if (2) is only possible for *some* categories, we have to take (1) for all, so even if (2) is appealing for concrete categories, we have to avoid it, right?

Comment: Why should we have to think about everything the same way? We don't even think of all groups the same way! See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2551/why-do-groups-and-abelian-groups-feel-so-different

Comment: @Charles: I will think about this, maybe I try to be unreasonabily rigorous.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Your last sentence in your edit convinces me. By the way, that's exactly what I had in mind yesterday when I said ""forget the inner structure of the objects" (what you claimed not to understand?).

Comment: That's not the part I didn't understand; you weren't clear about what kind of representations you wanted of the abstract thing.

Comment: Ah! I had in mind any standard representation of an unlabelled graph, e.g. an adjacency matrix (factored out by isomorphism). But that's off-topic here.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant.  You started with a poset of structured sets, regarded it as an abstract poset, and asked if we could recover the original structured sets.  You did not specify what kind of structure you wanted; it is totally conceivable that the poset you described could be recovered as the poset of some set of groups under inclusion, for example.  

Comment: @Hans: trying to think about everything the same way is not "trying to be unreasonably rigorous", as there is no rigorousness in it at all, but being a bit silly :)

Comment: I definitely did not expect this question to be silly, but if you think so, I have to live with that.

Comment: And I thought of category theory as a kind of unifying theory, why then not to think in a unified manner about its objects?

Comment: Then you agree that category theory shouldn't be bound by the properties of sets!  

Comment: In the final end: of course.


Answer (score 0):

Some (abstract) categories allow their objects and arrows to be "interpreted by themselves", without recurring to sets from set theory, especially poset categories via [Dedekind completions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut#Generalization%3a_Dedekind_completions_in_posets).

Answer (score 0):

Is this a helpful analogy?

Any categorical theory (whose models are all isomorphic) describes a structure uniquely up to isomorphism. In this case there is no need to start with a set-model and forget about it after it has done its work.

On the other hand: Only *non*-categorical theories give rise to full-blown concrete categories like that of groups with homomorphisms, topological spaces with continuous maps and so on.