# Why semigroups are important?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

There is known a lot about semigroups, mostly about their inner structure etc. But is there any use of semigroups in the general Maths -- like that of groups?

Comment: A similar (but to my mind much better) question is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20604/are-rings-really-more-fundamental-objects-than-semi-rings
I don't think this question is well-posed. Why is the wikipedia answer insufficient? 


Comment: Without saying what you mean by "the general Maths" this question is, as Daniel says, not well-posed.

Comment: The question has been re-asked at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55885